# How would you implement a simple strategy player controller in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

All player controllers in the C++ game templates are not for strategy games. They all implemented so the player controls just *one* character. I'm not sure what approach to take when you want to control several units.

What comes in mind: The player should not have a mesh. He should be always in the center of the screen, he will never move. mouse will then control selection/edge-pan instead of him moving.

In the following image, I have a sphere, that's a "Planet", I wish to accomplish that the player to control the planet, produce units, and control them. I'm very new to UE4, using version 4.6.1, any help would be appreciated as I found little in other places.

[image]

Here's my current implementation. it's just the default top down template:

```
// StrategyAlphaCharacter.h
#pragma once
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "StrategyAlphaCharacter.generated.h"

UCLASS(Blueprintable)
class AStrategyAlphaCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    /** Top down camera */
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Camera, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UCameraComponent* TopDownCameraComponent;

    /** Camera boom positioning the camera above the character */
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = Camera, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class USpringArmComponent* CameraBoom;


public:
    AStrategyAlphaCharacter(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);

    /** Returns TopDownCameraComponent subobject **/
    FORCEINLINE class UCameraComponent* GetTopDownCameraComponent() const { return TopDownCameraComponent; }
    /** Returns CameraBoom subobject **/
    FORCEINLINE class USpringArmComponent* GetCameraBoom() const { return CameraBoom; }
};


// StrategyAlphaCharacter.cpp
#include "StrategyAlpha.h"
#include "StrategyAlphaCharacter.h"

AStrategyAlphaCharacter::AStrategyAlphaCharacter(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
    : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    // Set size for player capsule
    GetCapsuleComponent()->InitCapsuleSize(42.f, 96.0f);

    // Don't rotate character to camera direction
    bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
    bUseControllerRotationYaw = false;
    bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;

    // Configure character movement
    GetCharacterMovement()->bOrientRotationToMovement = true; // Rotate character to moving direction
    GetCharacterMovement()->RotationRate = FRotator(0.f, 640.f, 0.f);
    GetCharacterMovement()->bConstrainToPlane = true;
    GetCharacterMovement()->bSnapToPlaneAtStart = true;

    // Create a camera boom...
    CameraBoom = ObjectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(this, TEXT("CameraBoom"));
    CameraBoom->AttachTo(RootComponent);
    CameraBoom->bAbsoluteRotation = true; // Don't want arm to rotate when character does
    CameraBoom->TargetArmLength = 800.f;
    CameraBoom->RelativeRotation = FRotator(-60.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    CameraBoom->bDoCollisionTest = false; // Don't want to pull camera in when it collides with level

    // Create a camera...
    TopDownCameraComponent = ObjectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(this, TEXT("TopDownCamera"));
    TopDownCameraComponent->AttachTo(CameraBoom, USpringArmComponent::SocketName);
    TopDownCameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = false; // Camera does not rotate relative to arm

}

// StrategyAlphaPlayerController.cpp
#include "StrategyAlpha.h"
#include "StrategyAlphaPlayerController.h"
#include "AI/Navigation/NavigationSystem.h"

AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::AStrategyAlphaPlayerController(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
    : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    bShowMouseCursor = true;
    DefaultMouseCursor = EMouseCursor::Crosshairs;
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::PlayerTick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::PlayerTick(DeltaTime);

    // keep updating the destination every tick while desired
    if (bMoveToMouseCursor)
    {
        MoveToMouseCursor();
    }
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::SetupInputComponent()
{
    // set up gameplay key bindings
    Super::SetupInputComponent();

    InputComponent->BindAction("SetDestination", IE_Pressed, this, &AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::OnSetDestinationPressed);
    InputComponent->BindAction("SetDestination", IE_Released, this, &AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::OnSetDestinationReleased);

    // support touch devices 
    InputComponent->BindTouch(EInputEvent::IE_Pressed, this, &AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::MoveToTouchLocation);
    InputComponent->BindTouch(EInputEvent::IE_Repeat, this, &AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::MoveToTouchLocation);
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::MoveToMouseCursor()
{
    // Trace to see what is under the mouse cursor
    FHitResult Hit;
    GetHitResultUnderCursor(ECC_Visibility, false, Hit);

    if (Hit.bBlockingHit)
    {
        // We hit something, move there
        SetNewMoveDestination(Hit.ImpactPoint);
    }
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::MoveToTouchLocation(const ETouchIndex::Type FingerIndex, const FVector Location)
{
    FVector2D ScreenSpaceLocation(Location);

    // Trace to see what is under the touch location
    FHitResult HitResult;
    GetHitResultAtScreenPosition(ScreenSpaceLocation, CurrentClickTraceChannel, true, HitResult);
    if (HitResult.bBlockingHit)
    {
        // We hit something, move there
        SetNewMoveDestination(HitResult.ImpactPoint);
    }
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::SetNewMoveDestination(const FVector DestLocation)
{
    APawn* const Pawn = GetPawn();
    if (Pawn)
    {
        UNavigationSystem* const NavSys = GetWorld()->GetNavigationSystem();
        float const Distance = FVector::Dist(DestLocation, Pawn->GetActorLocation());

        // We need to issue move command only if far enough in order for walk animation to play correctly
        if (NavSys && (Distance > 120.0f))
        {
            NavSys->SimpleMoveToLocation(this, DestLocation);
        }
    }
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::OnSetDestinationPressed()
{
    // set flag to keep updating destination until released
    bMoveToMouseCursor = true;
}

void AStrategyAlphaPlayerController::OnSetDestinationReleased()
{
    // clear flag to indicate we should stop updating the destination
    bMoveToMouseCursor = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at the [official UE4 Tower Defense sample/tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/SampleGames/StrategyGame/index.html)?

That sample demonstrates a UE4 project where the player is not associated with any one in-game character, instead providing building orders and high-level AI directives.